# How to get custom shape type from OpenOffice SDK?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I am using OpenOffice SDK to open and parse ppt and pptx files; now I can open ppt files and extract shapes.

```
XShape xShape = (XShape) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XShape.class, xShapes.getByIndex(j));
String type = xShape.getShapeType();
```

By using the code above I can get shape type and for rectangle, ellipse, etc., but I get `com.sun.star.drawing.CustomShape`.

Is there a way to get the shape type, like rectangle, ellipse, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find is getting **UINameSingular** property

```
XPropertySet xShapeProperties = (XPropertySet) 
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xShape);
String uiName = (String) xShapeProperties.getPropertyValue("UINameSingular");
```